# Stringify JSON in Logic App

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, stringify, azure-servicebus-topics

We are sending messages to a service bus using a logic app. These messages will later be consumed by another service, the service expects the message content to be a string - essentially a stringified JSON object, with escape characters.

We are not able to find a method to stringify a JSON object in Logic Apps. Even if we explicitly provide a escaped string the logic app itself detects that it's stringified JSON and unescapes it and then sends it as a JSON object. We don't want that, we simply want it to send the string as it is. We have already tried changing the content type to text/plain, it does not work. The logic app always sends the unescaped string as JSON.

This post on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e5dee958-09a7-4784-b1bf-facdd6b8a568/post-json-from-logic-app-how-to-escape-data?forum=azurelogicapps is of no help because doing this will violate the request contract of the message consuming service

Comment: If you could supply the sended message format will be more helpful. It is better that you could add the screenshot. Would you mind sharing what you expected message format or other service how to deal with the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the stringified message to include opening and closing double quotes?

I've tried this and it worked for me.

1. I have my JSON object as an output of a compose
2. Then, I initialised a variable with the Base64 encoded value of the escaped stringified JSON ***(you need to add ALL the proper escaping required,
   mine was just a PoC)***
3. Then, you send the variable already in Base64 to Service Bus. (You need to remove the encoding on that action).

   ```
   "actions": {
       "Compose_JSON_Object": {
           "inputs": {
               "message": "I want this as a string"
           },
           "runAfter": {},
           "type": "Compose"
       },
       "Initialise_Variable_with_Stringified_JSON_Base64_Encoded": {
           "inputs": {
               "variables": [
                   {
                       "name": "jsonAsStringBase64",
                       "type": "String",
                       "value": "@base64(concat('\"', replace(string(outputs('Compose_JSON_Object')), '\"', '\\\"'), '\"'))"
                   }
               ]
           },
           "runAfter": {
               "Compose_JSON_Object": [
                   "Succeeded"
               ]
           },
           "type": "InitializeVariable"
       },
       "Send_message": {
           "inputs": {
               "body": {
                   "ContentData": "@variables('jsonAsStringBase64')",
                   "ContentType": "text/plain"
               },
               "host": {
                   "connection": {
                       "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"
                   }
               },
               "method": "post",
               "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('temp'))}/messages",
               "queries": {
                   "systemProperties": "None"
               }
           },
           "runAfter": {
               "Initialise_Variable_with_Stringified_JSON_Base64_Encoded": [
                   "Succeeded"
               ]
           },
           "type": "ApiConnection"
       }
   },
   ```

This way, I got the message stringified.

HTH

Comment: Verified it works! Just a piece of advice, I often switch designer and code view when i was fixing this to make sure I did not make any syntax error.